# Appcelerator: Event when reopening App

Tags: ios, events, appcelerator, reload, multitasking

I want my app to reload data when it will be reopened (from iOS "Multitasking").

I've tested:

```
Ti.UI.addEventListener('reload', function() {
    alert('reloaded app');
});
```

but this event just gets fired when the App will be opened the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app entering the foreground is an **app level** event.  So you need to register on Ti.App, not Ti.UI.  In fact I can't find any reference to the event you are using.

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('resume', function() {
    alert('reloaded app');
});
```

Or you can use "resumed" for after it has completely returned.

See [this page](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.App-module)

Comment: If I use your code, I get the following error: [ERROR] Script Error = Result of expression 'Ti.App' [undefined] is not an object. at app.js (line 24).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code, unless Appcelerator has made a drastic change to the API.  You can see the exact code being used in this post (http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/126900/detect-when-app-loses-focus).  There must be something wrong with your setup.  Are you using a stable build or a nightly?

Comment: Also, if you just used Ti.App for the first time then you will need to clean the project (Titanium uses caching to speed up compiles and it only builds in modules that it needs, and won't check for new ones unless you do a clean build).